# Not using SSH Pubkey Authentication is really serious security flaw compare to regular Password Authentication

Tags: linux, security, ssh, firewall, csf

How would using *PubkeyAuthentication* would be more secure than using *PasswordAuthentication*, considering the following facts:

1. Default SSH port is moved from its default
2. Firewall blacklists an IP after few unsuccessful tries
3. Password looks pretty complicated (*14-20* senseless characters)

Comment: Never heard of a keylogger? They are some more advanced ones that capture keys, but primitive key loggers only capture what you type.  A public key with a strong pass phrase is in some ways a weak form of two factor authentication, since you  need to posses the key, and know the pass phrase.

Comment: I did hear about key-loggers! I wonder who would use SSH root access from the computer you don't trust - thus not your own computer? I realize that two step authentication would be better though!

Comment: Do you check every day to make sure there is no hardware keylogger sitting between your keyboard and the USB port where it's plugged in? If you work in a place with lax physical security, that's how easy it is to defeat password-based authentication.

Comment: I finally switched to using public key! Thanks, everybody!

Comment: Also moving the default port does not prevent an attack. The attacker can just run a port scan like nmap and find which port it's on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Your password has 12 characters, which at 6 bits per character is 72 bits of randomness. An SSH key is at least 2048 bits, which is a lot more to try to guess.
- An SSH key is stored on your client, only accessed by the SSH client, and not even known by you. A password is often used for other purposes (higher chance of leakage) and typed into untrusted environments.
- Under a MITM attack, attempting to authenticate with an SSH key does not leak the private key, whereas attempting password authentication does leak the password.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose somebody got your password from you by swiping the Post-it Note from under your keyboard? Or by [using a rubber hose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis). It would be mostly useless if password authentication is disabled.

Comment: Does that wikipedia link go where I think it does?

Comment: Yes. Yes it does.

Comment: Keeping the `Post-it Note` with 2048-bit password under your keyboard?  :)) Are you serious? Have you ever seen this kind of invigilance?     Using a `rubber hose` sounds more appropriate even though less possible!

Comment: Yes, I've seen such insanity. Even from sysadmins who _should_ know better.

Answer (score 1):

Pubkey authentication is stronger because the AAA hinges on a keypair, in effect a mathematical identity, rather than a string of characters (the password). One must possess the public portion to succeed in auth, and you cant just lean over a  shoulder or get it with a rubber hose. As for the comment about MITM...well, ssh doesn't transmit passwords in the clear.

Of course, there is more  you can do here beyond pubkeys:

- Limit the source IP's that can connect to that system

  - host firewall
  - TCP Wrappers
  - Reverse Proxy
- Use 'AllowUsers'  and 'Allowgroups' in sshd_config
- Use PAM, there are various modules that apply more security filteration
- Require pubkey auth as well as password,
- Set 'PermitRootLogin No' in sshd_config
- Set your 'ServerKeyBits' to 2048 in sshd_config
- Generate your pubkeys as 2048-bit or larger

Alternatives to pubkey auth?

- Use S/MIME, generate a list of one-time-passwords